# jQuery infinite vertical loop like slot machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making simple vertical loop animation with jQuery and I am stuck in the middle right now.

What I want to achieve firstly is make a vertical infinite loop animation like slot machine which is triggered by START button.(STOP button is not necessary this time). 
Here's my example.
http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/qWM56/

(I'm not a javascript expert, patchworked these codes from other source, so go easy on me.)

Secondary, I want to duplicate this chunk twice and make them align side by side like slot machine.

Need a little help.

Comment: Check this out http://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bn7Kq/5/ bit it is not perfectly synchron :-/ anyway.. i hope it helps you

Comment: to Wasim
Yes. I've checked the script before but that's little too much for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: to alphanyx
Wow. That was fast. love your modification. thanks. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used  alphanyx's version, added "last" class  to the last div to make it synchron:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bn7Kq/6/

Comment: Marcio Thank much!
The little trick you did was adding class 'last' to each last element, right?

Comment: np say thx to alphanyx for the code ;) i just figured out the sync problem

Comment: When i click start again i get undesired scrolling. Take a look closely